# MySQL - true/false query returning different on two servers

Tags: mysql, sql

Confused on this one.

Same version of MySQL running on both servers.  (built from exact same rpm's) - somewhere along the line some developer changed something...

Server 1:

```
mysql> select ( not 1 = 2 );

0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Server 2:

```
mysql> select ( not 1 = 2 );

1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Both servers:

```
mysql> sHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';

| version       | 5.6.12 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the [`HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_high_not_precedence) operator.

The official documentation states:

> The precedence of the NOT operator is such that expressions such as NOT a BETWEEN b AND c are parsed as NOT (a BETWEEN b AND c). In some older versions of MySQL, the expression was parsed as (NOT a) BETWEEN b AND c. The old higher-precedence behavior can be obtained by enabling the HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE SQL mode.

Fiddle to test this behaviour [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d41d8/333).

By the way, I would recommend to compare `x != y` rather than using `not (x = y)`.